# Using googlemaps timezone python client

Tags: python

I am trying to get timezone from googlemaps timezone python client from this location [GoogleMaps Python client](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python)

However i could not make it work, there is no example for it as well. I tried as below but could not get any output, any help would be appreciated

```
from googlemaps import timezone
print(timezone.timezone("APIKEY",[20,114]))
```

Comment: Running `help(timezone.timezone)` may provide some documentation.

Comment: actually it dint help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is old, but for future people who come across it, I almost opened a similar question, but figured it out myself. Here is what I did:

```
from googlemaps import Client
from googlemaps.timezone import timezone

gmaps = Client(key='mykey')
point = (latitude, longitude)
gmaps.timezone(point)
```

This way worked for me.